I am basically having doubt about where Lorentz transformation is being applied?
I was solving example 12.14 in Griffiths' Introduction to Electrodynamics) The question was:

A point charge $q$ is at rest at the origin in system $S_{0}.$ What is the electric fieldof this same charge in system $S$, which moves to the right at speed $v_{0}$ relative to $S_{0}$?

Now the solution uses the Lorentz transformation in $y$ and $z$ coordinate for $E.$ Shouldn't it be only for $x$ but not $y$ and $z$ (they are perpendicular to $x$ direction, right?)
$$E_{x}=E_{x0}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\frac{qx_{0}}{(x_{0}^{2}+y_{0}^{2}+z_{0}^{2})^{3/2}}, \\
E_{y}=\gamma_{0}E_{y0}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\frac{\gamma_{0}qy_{0}}{(x_{0}^{2}+y_{0}^{2}+z_{0}^{2})^{3/2}}, \\
E_{z}=\gamma_{0}E_{z0}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\frac{\gamma_{0}qz_{0}}{(x_{0}^{2}+y_{0}^{2}+z_{0}^{2})^{3/2}}.$$
Can anyone please help explain this?
Please note:  I'm interested in understanding the concept here as opposed to the particular solution to this example from the text.  Why is it that the field in the direction of motion is unchanged, whilst the perpendicular directions are scaled by $\gamma_{0}?$  This seems counter-intuitive, since generally speaking there is spatial contraction in the direction of motion and not in the perpendicular directions.

Don't post images/screenshots of equations (or text). Instead, use MathJax.

You actually have to transform all components, but some of them might have a trivial transformation. Check what are the transformation laws for the electromagnetic fields (I'm sure Griffiths has that equation somewhere)

It is difficult to explain something just because you find it "counterintuitive". The answer is that the equations work and they work correctly. Please clarify the exact conceptual issue you're experiencing, rather than simply claiming that you find it "counterintuitive".

Simply compute $F^{\prime \mu \nu}(x) =L^\mu_\alpha L^\nu_\beta F^{\alpha \beta}(L^{-1} x)$ and forget your "intuition".  If you prefer, you may use matrix notation $F^\prime(x)=LF(L^{-1}x)L^T$. Be aware that "intuition"  in physics can only be achieved by a lot of experience.

@Hyperon Exactly.

The title of the question is unclear.

Electric field is only one part of the electromagnetic field, that in SR is mathematically represented by a $2^{nd}$-order tensor, whose contravariant components are $F^{\mu\nu}$.
The transformation rule of the components of a $2^{nd}$-order tensor reads
$$\tilde{F}^{\alpha \beta} = \Lambda_{\mu}^{\alpha} \Lambda_{\nu}^{\beta} F^{\mu \nu} \ ,$$
with $\Lambda_{\mu}^{\alpha}$ the components of the matrix representing a Lorentz transformation, that for the components of 4-vector reads
$$\tilde{x}^{\mu} = \Lambda^{\mu}_{\nu} x^{\nu}$$
Using Cartesian coordinates for two systems in standard configuration, the transformation of the components of a vector reads
$$\begin{cases}
  \tilde{x}^0 = c \tilde{t} = \gamma ct - \gamma v x  = \gamma x^0 - \gamma v x^1 \\
  \tilde{x}^1 = \tilde{x} = -\gamma ct + \gamma x = -\gamma x^0 + \gamma v x^1 \\
  \tilde{x}^2 = x^2 \\
  \tilde{x}^3 = x^3 \ .
\end{cases}$$
Now, keeping in mind the bases we are referring to, it's possible to use matrix formalism (remember that tensors are not matrices!), it's possible to write
$$\begin{bmatrix} \tilde{x}^0 \\  \tilde{x}^1 \\  \tilde{x}^2 \\  \tilde{x}^3 \\ \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} \gamma & -\gamma v & & \\ - \gamma v & \gamma & & \\ & & 1 & \\ & & & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}  x^0 \\ x^1 \\ x^2 \\ x^3 \end{bmatrix}$$
and the components of the electromagnetic tensor transform as
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -\underline{\tilde{e}}^T / c \\ \frac{\underline{\tilde{e}}}{c} & \underline{\tilde{b}}_{\times} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \gamma & -\gamma v & & \\ - \gamma v & \gamma & & \\ & & 1 & \\ & & & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -\underline{e}^T / c \\ \frac{\underline{e}}{c} & \underline{b}_{\times} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \gamma & -\gamma v & & \\ - \gamma v & \gamma & & \\ & & 1 & \\ & & & 1 \end{bmatrix} \ . $$
You should get the transformation you need, setting the magnetic field $\underline{b} = \underline{0}$ and performing matrix multiplication.


Now the solution uses the Lorentz transformation in 
and   coordinate for .
Shouldn't it be only for  but not  and  (they are perpendicular to 
direction, right?)

You are thinking of performing a Lorentz boost Transformation on the components of a 4-vector.
However, the electric field is actually part of an anti-symmetric 4-tensor $F_{ab}$, as hinted by one of the comments.
So, the transformation formula for the components of a 4-tensor like $F_{ab}$ are not the same as that of a 4-vector.
I did a calculation in tensor notation at
https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/the-electric-field-seen-by-an-observer-a-relativistic-calculation-with-tensors/ .

The main idea is that the electric field and magnetic fields components are certain components of an antisymmetric-tensor $F_{ab}$. For a given observer, the components are determined by using the observer's 4-velocity to break up $F_{ab}$ into electric and magnetic parts.

For a second observer, whose 4-velocity is related by a Lorentz boost transformation of the first-observer's 4-velocity, we can see how to transform the first-observer's electric and magnetic components into those of the second observer.

Although parts may be too advanced, you could get a glimpse of how the formulas arise.

UPDATE:
[Ignoring sign-conventions, index-positions, and other notations...] the field tensor $F_{ab}$ is a two-form which can be expressed in rectangular form:
$$\tilde F=
E_x (dt \wedge dx)+E_y (dt \wedge dy)+E_z (dt \wedge dz)
+B_x (dy \wedge dz)+B_y (dz \wedge dx)+B_z (dx \wedge dy)
$$
(where the components of $B$ are zero in your problem).
When the basis covectors are related by a boost along the x-direction, we have:
\begin{eqnarray*}
dt &=& \gamma dt' - \beta\gamma dx'\\
dx &=& -\beta\gamma dt' + \gamma dx'\\
dy &=& dy'\\
dz &=& dz'
\end{eqnarray*}
So,
\begin{eqnarray*}
dt \wedge dx
&=& (\gamma dt' - \beta\gamma dx') \wedge (-\beta\gamma dt' + \gamma dx')\\
&=& \gamma^2 dt' \wedge dx'  + \beta^2\gamma^2 dx' \wedge dt'\\
&=&dt' \wedge dx'
\end{eqnarray*}
which suggests that $E_x=E_x'$.
Similarly,
\begin{eqnarray*}
dt \wedge dy
&=& (\gamma dt' - \beta\gamma dx') \wedge dy'\\
&=& \gamma dt' \wedge dy'  - \beta\gamma dx' \wedge dy'
\end{eqnarray*}
which suggests that $E_y=\gamma E_y'$.
You can do the $dt \wedge dz$ case.

A charge moving in some direction will have its field lines contracted when they are at least partially perpendicular to the direction of motion! Think about an imaginary box or sphere that surrounds the charge (point charges themselves have no spatial length and cannot be contracted.) This box or sphere will be contracted along the direction of motion and will squeeze the field lines up, but not a field line that is in the direction of motion.
